# React - render() method - difference between calling {renderG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble finding out what the differences are between adding something *in the render method* as a *component*...

```js
/// components/profilePic.js

export const ProfilePic = () => {
 return (
   <Image src={props.src} />
 )
 
 
 
/// App.js

import { ProfilePic } from './components'

render() {
 return (
   <View>
     // This line here  vvv
     <ProfilePic src={"user/profilepic"} />
   </View>
 )
}
```

vs. using a *function that returns JSX*:

```js
/// components/profilePic.js

export const profilePic = (src) => {
 return (
   <Image src={src} />
 )
 
 
 
/// App.js

import { profilePic } from './components'

render() {
 return (
   <View>
     // This line here  vvv
     {profilePic("user/profilepic")}
   </View>
 )
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine and should result in the same output.
For this particular usecase, it is recommended to use the first approach to maintain the JSX standard and for improved readability.

One usecase I can think of for the second method is when you need to render an array of elements for example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.images.map((image) => <Image src={image} /> )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this case, the callback to `map` can be extracted as a separate function. Here, the purpose of doing that is easy testability of the functionality

```
const getImage = (imageSrc) => <Image src={imageSrc} />;

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.images.map(getImage)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to call Hooks inside Javascript functions. Check these [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). That is why it is always better to render components as React functions, so that hooks can be added if required.

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions **Don’t call Hooks from regular
> JavaScript functions**. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom
> Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page). By following this
> rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly
> visible from its source code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor difference between a functional component and a component that returns JSX

A functional component can make use of other react related APIs like `React.memo`, `React.forwardRef` and also `you can define hooks` within a functional component

Whereas a function doesn't have that much flexibility

While a some cases you can go ahead and implement a certain logic as a function(where the rendering logic is minimum. Eg mapping and returning elements), A functional component can be modified to have much more logic easily and also be optimised for higher performance